# "We love Stack Overflow" div with invisible content

Tags: bug, design

As of today, I am looking at the following blank space between the navigation bar and the tag description in my tagged feed:

[image: screenshot]

The "offending" empty `div` seems to be some sort of ad (its id starts with `adzerk`) and its class is `everyonelovesstackoverflow`, which has the following style:

```
.everyonelovesstackoverflow:empty {
    height: 90px;
    width: 728px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
.everyonelovesstackoverflow {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

This glitch survives a cache/offline website data cleanup and page reload.

I'm observing it in FireFox ESR 45.8.0.

Is this some sort of bug?

Comment: Also  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/tag-page-shows-lots-of-empty-space

Comment: Agreed, duplicate. Never quite figured out whether I should vote to close my own, or just delete...